# I have created 1 server which connect one client in another PC and another one as Localhost?

Tags: python, tcp, tcpclient, gethostbyname

I need run my client 2 times. The first time I need run using local network PC and the next time I need to use as a local host. I need to run  server  in loop and both need to be connected using `GET HOST BY NAME()`.

How to change the line in server and the client.

## Server

```
host= raw input("Enter the IP Address: " )
port= 8521
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_ INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
```

## Client

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the Host = Socket.gethostname()so that once commutation port in open it will listen to the Same IP which has the same port Number